# Vim Tabular Plugin to align two columns of text?

Tags: vim, tabular

Worked my way through a number of [Tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) pages but cannot figure this out. I want to align two columns of text. The first column is a single word, and the second column is the rest of the line:

```
alpha one oclock hey
beta two oclock hey
phi three oclock hey
```

I'd like to align it to be:

```
alpha one oclock hey
beta  two oclock hey
phi   three oclock hey
```

Also, it is possible for these lines to be already indented, so there can be spaces and tabs to the left of the first word.

I cannot figure out the regexp to make this happen. Can someone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this command:

```
:Tabularize /^\S\+\zs/l0c1l0
```

- `^\S\+\zs` will match position after first column
- `l0c1l0` means column alignment and width.

Comment: Okay that did it. I ended up with `Tabularize /^\s*\S\+\zs/l0c1l0`. Thanks!